# How to achieve a glowy/dreamy light look

Tags: light, editing

I have noticed some photos have this glowy/dreamy light effect. I am not sure how this is achieved (shooting/editing??). Does anyone know? I have included an example. [image]

Comment: photoshop: duplicate image, add blur, set opacity

Comment: old school: soft focus filter https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/609131-REG/Nikon_4930_77_Soft_Focus_Filter.html

Comment: Might just be me, but it looks like the contrast on this one was lowered as well. Saturation seems a bit less too.

Answer (score 1):

An OOOOLD trick: use a womens nylon stocking and clamp it over the lens.

Comment: The "granny" style ones that only came up to about 3/4 of the way from the ankle to the knee were easier to use and stuff in the bottom of your camera bag.